# LED Indicator on 3v3 SPI Bus

Tags: led, spi, sd

I have a 3v3 SPI bus with a SDcard on it. I would like to know visually when data is being written to the card. Are there any potential problems with adding a small (1206) SMD LED in parallel as an indicator?

Comment: If you control the bus, then implement the led on your own MCU. If not, what about just on the Chip-Select line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problems about your idea:

- a SPI bus runs fast, so if you connect a LED to the data signals or chip select you will not see anything .. its to fast for your eye.
- the led need some current, the spi pins have to drive the current for it.

a solution could be to use the chip select signal with a transistor to trigger a pulse element with drive a led for a  short time.

Comment: That is good to identify when data is written *or read*. Ligthing the LED only for writes (as it seems written in the question) would be much more complex, though. But maybe the question was simply missing that point.

Comment: true, if only on write actions the LED should flash you have definitively to control the LED from your SPI Master Device

Comment: "you will not see anything" - not true, if the write takes long enough you will see the LED at varying levels of brightness. (You still won't see it flicker on and off several million times a  second)